# Adding MS Access Database to Project in Visual Studio 2010 Express

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2010, ms-access, project

My post title pretty much sums it up. Busy with a project in Visual Studio 2010 Express and just need to add a AccessDB.accdb to my project so that I can reference **AccessDBDataSet** in my code...

I seemed to be successful by adding the database to the project but when I try and reference the data-set I just get an error saying that my project doesn't contain a definition for the data-set and no extension method etc etc.

Thanks!

Comment: Sensitive question I see lol...

Answer (score 2):

If you're asking how to connect to and use a Microsoft Access database to store information you'll want to look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ybdbtte(v=vs.71).aspx

You can set it up a couple of ways either visually or with some code. Then scroll down and look at using that connection to create and use Recordsets like this link here for ADO.net recordsets ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s3saad7(v=vs.71).aspx ). Recordsets are, I assume, what you're asking about. Those are a way you can interact with Datasets as you say.

The downvotes are probably a matter of not being clear enough.